# CSS HTML How to make sidebar height connect to footer

Tags: html, css, height, sidebar

I want to code page where sidebar height is "100%" - connect with footer. There is image of this: [image]

I did it using absolute divs but I'm not satisfied with this effect. I wrote this badly. Could you give me some code/advice how to code this?

Comment: Please post the code you've tried already.

Comment: `table-cell` or `flex`

Comment: This is not an actual question but you should check this http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Answer (score 1):

2015 is coming very soon, man. Give [**Flexible Box Layout**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) a try. It's been [**supported by all major browsers**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) now. If you find W3C spec hard to read, [**this article**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) might give you a quick lesson.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  height: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
}
section {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
aside {
  width: 100px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
article {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
}
footer {
  height: 40px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<section>
  <aside>sidebar</aside>
  <article>body</article>
</section>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: Could you explain what does it exactly do? the w3 manual is quite hard to read.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde The code is almost self-explained. If you feel it hard to understand, but don't want to read the spec, [**this article**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) might help.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde If you find it useful and worth learning after reading and trying, don't forget to come back and upvote :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use css with `display:table-cell` like this

```css
header {
}

section {
  display: table;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

aside {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: green;
}

article {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: blue;
  width: *;
}

footer {
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<section>
  <aside>
    sidebar
  </aside>
  <article>
    lorem ipsum...
  </article>
</section>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: It doesn't works correctly. Look my edited post above.

Comment: If you want the red bar to appear if it goes all the way down to the footer, the you could perhaps better just use a background gradient in css to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have the code (simplify): http://jsfiddle.net/L4k9gwqw/

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            Header
        </header>
        <section>
            <aside>
                Here<br />is<br />Side<br />
            </aside>
            <article>
                Content here<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                <br /><br /><br />Dynamic height
            </article>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </section>
        <footer>
            Footer
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
header {
    background:#5ee;
    width: 800px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
section {
    padding-bottom:80px;   /* Height of the footer element */
    border: 1px dashed red;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
aside {
    background: #70ee83;
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
}
article {
    width: 540px;
    float: right;
    background: orange;
}
footer {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ee5;
}
```

I am using here [this code for footer always bottom](http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/). I want that sidebar (aside) always connect with footer, but content (article) not necessarily.

**EDIT: ** `display: table` and `display: table-cell` for section and aside&article doesnt' works. I want to get this effect: [image]. I don't know how to code this red menu beginning from footer and ending in aside.